# Dictionary for JSON file format

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary of lists that I want to store in a JSON file in a particular format.

Format:

```
{ "type" : 
     {"name" : "Predicted", "inward" : "is predicted by", "outward" : "predicts"},
                 "inwardIssue" : { "key" : issues_key[1]},
                 "outwardIssue":{"key":data2}
    }
```

Data in Dictionary:

```
{'CLOV-1984': ['CLOV-1979'], 'CLOV-1979': ['CLOV-1984'], 'CLOV-1970': ['CLOV-1951'], 'CLOV-1951': ['CLOV-1970'], 'CLOV-1910': ['CLOV-1909'], 'CLOV-1909': ['CLOV-1910'], 'CLOV-1853': ['CLOV-1849', 'CLOV-1845', 'CLOV-1842'], 'CLOV-1849': ['CLOV-1853', 'CLOV-1840'], 'CLOV-1845': ['CLOV-1853', 'CLOV-1840'], 'CLOV-1842': ['CLOV-1853', 'CLOV-1840'], 'CLOV-1840': ['CLOV-1849', 'CLOV-1845', 'CLOV-1842']}
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-76678d843e45> in <module>
      8      {"name" : "Predicted", "inward" : "is predicted by", "outward" : "predicts"},
      9                  "inwardIssue" : { "key" : issues_key[1]},
---> 10                  "outwardIssue":{"key":data2}
     11     }
     12 })

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I am new to Python and trying different stuff.

```
import json


data = {}
data2 = []
data2 = dictIssues[issues_key[1]]
print(data2)
data['CLOV-1985'] = []
data['CLOV-1985'].append({
     { "type" : 
      {"name" : "Predicted", "inward" : "is predicted by", "outward" : 
          "predicts"},
                 "inwardIssue" : { "key" : issues_key[1]},
                 "outwardIssue":{"key":data2}
     }

})


with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

I should create a loop that goes through all the keys in the dictionary and get the lists and put it in a format for a JSON file.

Comment: You are actually not appending a dictionary, but a set `{}` is also used to build sets, and you are putting a dictionary inside, so that is why you get the error.

Comment: I didnt get what you mean?

Comment: The argument to `append` is a set literal, with a single element of type `dict`. Just drop the outermost set of braces: `data['CLOV-1985'].append({"type": ... })`.

Comment: yep. gotcha.. thanks

Comment: You should really extrat and provide a [mcve] along with your question. It is not just required but it also helps you solve your own problem. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].